# Get results from one table based on "filter" table efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, Table A contains sales data, while table B has some columns from table A that will need to act as a filter to get matching results from table A.  I can get the result I need, but it takes a long time, and I suspect the way I am doing it is not very efficient. This logic is used in multiple databases, so sometimes tables A and B are small and this only takes a second, other databases are much larger though, with records in each table in the 10's, possibly 100's of thousands.

Here is a demo script for both tables, there are more columns than this in production, but this gets the point across:

```
Create Table A
(
    ID int Identity(1,1),
    City nvarchar(255),
    State nvarchar(255),
    Zip nvarchar(255),
    Territory nvarchar(255)
)

Insert Into A Values 
('Chicago', 'IL', 'Zip1', 'Territory1'),
('Houston', 'TX', 'Zip2', 'Territory2'),
('Atlanta', 'AL', 'Zip3', 'Territory3'),
('Denver', 'CO', 'Zip4', 'Territory4'),
('Detroit', 'MI', 'Zip5', 'Territory1'),
('Seattle', 'WA', 'Zip6', 'Territory5'),
('Springfield', 'IL', 'Zip7', 'Territory1'),
('Springfield', 'MO', 'Zip8', 'Territory1'),
('Tacoma', 'WA', 'Zip10', 'Territory5'),
('Portland', 'OR', 'Zip10', 'Territory5' )


Create Table B
(
    ID int Identity(1,1),
    City nvarchar(255),
    State nvarchar(255),
    Zip nvarchar(255),
    Territory nvarchar(255)
)

Insert Into B Values
('Chicago', NULL, NULL, NULL),
('Springfield', 'IL', NULL, 'Territory1'),
(NULL, NULL, 'Zip2', NULL),
(NULL, 'WA', NULL, 'Territory5')
```

What I have to get the records needed looks like this:

```
Select * 
from A inner join B
on A.City like Coalesce(B.City, A.City)
and A.State like Coalesce(B.State, A.State)
and A.Zip like Coalesce(B.Zip, A.Zip)
and A.Territory like Coalesce(B.Territory, A.Territory)
--More joins in production for remaining columns
```

This works but with the amount of records and additional joins we have it takes a while for some of the databases. Is there any way to speed this up, or handle this more efficiently that I am not seeing?

Comment: Do you have the ability to check/update your indexing?  That might be your first step.  I'd also rethink the actual joining; if I'm not mistaken, the coalesce might be slowing it down.   Check the execution plan on the query too.  I'll try to think of a possible rewrite, based on what you've given.

Comment: Yes, can and have updated the indexes based on the execution plan, it helped, but not as much as I would have expected.  I did try ISNULL as well, but seems to get around the same time executed

Answer (score 2):

First of all,Its highly recommended to avoid using `like` for strings unless you don't have any choices, beside your business, I think your query would be much faster by a bit changes like below:

```
Select * 
from A inner join B
on (A.City =B.City OR B.City IS NULL)
and (A.State =B.State OR B.State IS NULL)
and (A.Zip =B.Zip OR B.Zip IS NULL)
and (A.Territory =B.Territory OR B.Territory IS NULL)
```

Comment: I can't get away from using like, some of the columns are business names.  So we get things like abc inc and abc co. So table B is given to us as abc(%) to catch all the iterations

Comment: This would make sense as to why you saw no difference between the isnull and coalesce also.

Comment: If you are forced to use like syntax, at least you can remove Coalesce from your query

Answer (score 1):

Exact matching including conditionals might be a better choice provided at least one of those four columns ( `A.City`, `A.State`,`A.Zip`,`A.Territory` ) has index on them :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM A 
  JOIN B
    ON CASE WHEN B.City is null THEN A.City ELSE B.City END = A.City
   AND CASE WHEN B.State is null THEN A.State else B.State END = A.State 
   AND CASE WHEN B.Zip is null THEN A.Zip ELSE B.Zip END = A.Zip
   AND CASE WHEN B.Territory is null THEN A.Territory ELSE B.Territory END = A.Territory
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of an ISNULL option in your where clause over the CASE option, but sounds like you have options.

```
Select * 
from A inner join B
on (A.City = isnull(B.City, A.City))
and (A.State = isnull(B.State, A.State))
and (A.Zip = isnull(B.Zip, A.Zip))
and (A.Territory = isnull(B.Territory, A.Territory))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Exact matching, creating indexes on columns used to join tables would also speed up your queries.

Comment: Its a comment not an answer !